# Phaser.js : cannot read property '0' on tiled map layer

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, phaser-framework

I'm working with Paser.js on a Meteor.js server.

It worked wperfectly until I try to use tiled maps as described [here](http://blog.hovercraft.ie/post/119437806421/creating-a-platformer-tilemap-for-phaser).

Here is my code :

JS :

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.Game.onCreated(function()
  {
    var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', {
       preload: preload,
       create: create,
       update: update
    });
    var map;
    var backgroundLayer;
    var blockLayer;
    var bg;
function preload()
{
  // load all game assets
  // images, spritesheets, atlases, audio etc..
  game.load.tilemap('myTilemap', 'assets/tilemaps/scifi.json', null, Phaser.Tilemap.TILED_JSON);
  game.load.image('myTileset', "assets/tilemaps/scifi_platformTiles_32x32.png");
}

function create()
{
  map = game.add.tilemap('myTilemap');
  map.addTilesetImage('scifi_platformTiles_32x32', 'myTileset');

  backgroundLayer = map.createLayer('background');
  blockLayer = map.createLayer('blocklayer');
}

function update()
{

}
  });
}
```

HTML :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Phaser - Making your first game, part 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to my first Phaser game!</h1>

  {{> Game}}
</body>

<template name="Game">
  <div id="phaserCanvas"></div>
</template>
```

And, when I try it on localhost:3000, I get :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

From phaser.min.js:15. The line which generate that warning is

```
blockLayer = map.createLayer('blocklayer');
```

It seems that phaser can correctly read the `'background'` layer information from the scifi.json, but not the `'blocklayer'` one.

Here is an extract from the scifi.json :

```
{ "height":20,
 "layers":[
        {
         "compression":"zlib",
         "data": "[Some very long hashed key...]",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":20,
         "name":"background",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":20,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }, 
        {
         "compression":"zlib",
         "data":"[Some very long hashed key...]",
         "encoding":"base64",
         "height":20,
         "name":"blocklayer",
         "opacity":1,
         "type":"tilelayer",
         "visible":true,
         "width":20,
         "x":0,
         "y":0
        }],
 "nextobjectid":1,
[...]
```

And I'm stil unable to find out what's the problem... Has anyone faced that before ?

More informations :

- I use Atom as IDE
- I tried with Phaser v2.0.1 and Phaser v2.4.2

Thanks you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems the problem came from Tiled : the hashed key was compressed with Zlib, though it should not be compressed at all as phaser do not support it yet.

Comment: To fix the error, in Tiled go to Map -> Map properties -> Tile Layer Format and choose CSV. Then export the new .json file.

Answer (score 4):

In tiled, go to Map -> Map Properties
There you will find Tile Layer Format. Change this to Base64 (uncompressed) and it should work :)